# Little to no collinearity (low VIF), but extremely high path coefficients

Tags: multiple-regression, multicollinearity

Consider a simple mediation model with three variables: independent variable, mediator, and dependent or outcome variable. Three paths between these variables: path a goes from independent variable to mediator, path b from the mediator to the dependent variable, and path c from the independent variable directly to the dependent variable.

I am attempting to fit a path model with these variables. I fit the model to the data and I am receiving a very high coefficient for the path between the mediator and outcome variable (i.e., path b in the model). The standardized coefficient for this path was greater than 1.

I tested for collinearity between the independent variable and mediator variable, and the output indicated that there was not problematic collinearity between them (VIF values close to 1).

My question is, can I live with or justify this coefficient estimate? That is, does this just mean my mediator variable has a very strong effect on the dependent variable (i.e., very high path b estimate)?